# vba object required error in sumif/sumifs functions using date condition

Tags: vba, excel

I use this line in vba:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("U5").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ActiveSheet.Range("U2:U4").Value, ">" & Date - 721, ActiveSheet.Range("T2:T4").Value)
```

and i get an

> Object required error

I think it's because the `Date`, but I'm not sure what is the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `.Value` property in the `SumIf` because the function expects `Range`s as arguments. This should work:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("U5").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ActiveSheet.Range("U2:U4"), ">" & Date - 721, ActiveSheet.Range("T2:T4"))
```

In this case the intellisense prompts this and you can apply this to the third parameter as well:

[image]

Comment: 16 seconds faster , but I had to add the `With` statement, does that count ? :)

Comment: Sure it counts ;)

Answer (score 1):

`WorksheetFunction.SumIf` function first parameter is a `Range`, not a `Value`; same goes for the third parameter.

**Note**: try not to rely on `ActiveSheet`.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    .Range("U5").Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Range("U2:U4"), ">" & Date - 721, .Range("T2:T4"))
End With
```